# IDEA 15 cannot resolve build.sbt after create SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

As the title, I've tried most solutions on the internet, but it still not work.
But I can still load my old SBT projects! 
It just can't create a new one.

Remove .lock file under ~./ivy2 and ~/.sbt => not work

Change sbt and scala version (Current version is SBT 13.9, Scala 2.11.7) => not work

Invalidate cache and restart => not work

Set SDK/Java path => not work
Reinstall => not work

Does anyone know what's going on?

`01:01:48 SBT project import
         [warn]     [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.9!compiler-interface.jar(src):  (0ms)
         [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
         [warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
         [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
         [warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
         [warn] ==== local: tried
         [warn]   /Users/WeiChen/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
         [warn] ==== activator-local: tried
         [warn]   /Users/WeiChen/activator-dist-1.3.6/repository/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
         [warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
         [warn]   /Users/WeiChen/.activator/repository/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/srcs/compiler-interface-sources.jar
         [warn] ==== public: tried
         [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sb..`

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with the latest update of Intellij. I believe it is Intellij bug since I still can do sbt compile without compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug on IDEA 15, I temporally downgrade to IDEA 14 to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing the project.

Select your build.sbt from the tree, then in the following dialog, make sure `Sources for SBT and plugins` is ticked.
[image]